# Banshee: Sort playlist by track number

Tags: banshee

Banshee has an option - sort playlist by track number, which does nothing when clicked. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: I think this is indeed a bug. There is some discussion about this problem on the banshee bug tracker here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/144173

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the Order is Artist>Album>Track number, not just track number.

In fact, also your songs are ordered this way.

Comment: if I want to sort that by Track number > Artist > Album?

Comment: Use another player. There are a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/144173), they are ordered as Artist > Album > Track Number, so you have:

```
1 - artist a - album 1
2 - artist a - album 1
...
1 - artist a - album 2
...
1 - artist b - album 1
...
```